# Is there a way to avoid precompiling assets in a test env for Rails for E2E tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) for E2E testing and it requires adding a `rake assets:precompile` step to my CI build commands. On average it takes about 4 minutes, which is just as long as the tests themselves. When I run tests locally, I don't need to precompile so I would assume that on CI that it wouldn't either but it does. I even have `config.assets.compile = true` on my `test.rb` file but it still needs the actually rake precompile task.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `env`

`config.assets.compile = ENV["COMPILE_ASSETS"] || false`

for example `COMPILE_ASSETS` exists then compile, otherwise sets to `false`

`RAILS_ENV=test COMPILE_ASSETS=true rake assets:precompile`

Comment: `config.assets.compile = false`  isn't actually doing anything on CI